# Should a sprint planning meeting be held before the previous sprint has ended?

Tags: agile, scrum

I am currently working in a team where we are doing the planning aprox halfway through the previous sprint. 
We start a 2 week sprint on a Monday, and the following Tuesday (1 week later) we have a planning meeting for the following sprint to start in a weeks time. We also conduct a weekly backlog grooming meeting where we prepare stories for planning.

- Is this normal? My scrum master says this is a common method and widely used.
- Is there any source of information for the case of holding the planning during the previous sprint?
- Does anyone have an opinion on the pros/cons of doing this?

I agree that it seems unusual, but I need some good reasons for doing it. I can't bring this up only knowing the negatives. Is there any justification for doing the planning before the end of a sprint?

Comment: Where is the exception?

Comment: @Giorgi - Sorry I don't understand your comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this normal? My scrum master says this is a common method and widely used.

**No**. He is incorrect. One sprint ends with a sprint review meeting. Then, the next sprint begins with a sprint planning meeting. Another meeting that happens during a sprint is a Product Backlog Refinement (aka Grooming) meeting.

> Is there any source of information for the case of holding the planning during the previous sprint?

There appears to be no source of such information, other than **your** Scrum Master.

> Does anyone have an opinion on the pros/cons of doing this?

Yes. It wastes time for at least two reasons:

- It takes up time, during the sprint, when other work (such as perhaps backlog refinement) could be done.
- The planning that is accomplished in that meeting may need to be re-planned at the beginning of the next sprint.

> ...I need some pros, some good reasons for doing it. I can't bring this up only knowing the negatives.

Really, **there are only negatives**.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I very much agree with all you have said. To date I cannot find a single piece of supporting evidence for this method so I am left to assume it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

That approach is quite unusual for several reasons.

Firstly, you don't know how the remainder of the sprint will go. It is quite possible some work will be incomplete and may need to be considered for the next sprint.

Secondly, the whole idea of Scrum is to get feedback from the stakeholders at the end of sprint showcase and feed this in to planning. If you have already decided on the content of the next sprint it implies you do not care what the stakeholders say.

I coached a team recently that had been doing planning 2-3 days before the end of the sprint. They had encountered numerous problems including having to carry over unfinished work and being forced to re-plan after the showcase. After we moved the planning sessions to the beginning of the sprint these problems went away.

Comment: I totally agree but I need some pros, some good reasons for doing it. I can't bring this up only knowing the negatives. Is there any justification for doing the planning before the end of a sprint?

Comment: It may be that there is a lot of pressure to provide forecasts, and this may support those forecasts. There is, however, no reason the Product owner can make these forecasts himself based on past velocity and current estimates.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of any advantages with this approach. Some teams are very busy towards the end of a sprint as they backload a lot of the testing. It could be argued that doing planning one week before the end of the sprint means they have extra time at the end of the sprint to carry on working. I'm not really convinced this is much of an advantage though!

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent long planning meetings I would suggest doing timeboxed "[Backlog refinement meetings](http://blogs.collab.net/agile/the-backlog-refinement-meeting-or-backlog-grooming#.VXbHb8-qpBc)" during the sprint. Depending on the Sprint lenght and the uncertainty of the product backlog I would schedule one short session each week, unless you are doing one week Sprints.

The actual sprint commitment still **only** happens in the Sprint planning meeting, which starts after the previous Sprint ends.

But having the extra "estimation and planning" meetings during the Sprint will make the life of PO easier, the backlog more clear and the planning meetings shorter. Although not part of the official Scrum I can advocate for doing "[Backlog refinement meetings](http://blogs.collab.net/agile/the-backlog-refinement-meeting-or-backlog-grooming#.VXbHb8-qpBc)" during each Sprint.

Comment: There is already a weekly backlog grooming meeting where we prepare stories for planning. This is primarily done for the reason of reducing the length planning meeting and giving people a heads up of what's to come.

Comment: What I really want to know is why would you do your one and only sprint planning meeting aprox 1 week before the actual sprint and aprox 1 week before the previous sprint has ended?

Comment: And please let me know if there is any supporting documentation for this implementation of the planning meeting

Comment: Sounds good, I thought your planning sessions was actually a refinement session. I have never heard or read about planning meetings during the sprint, maybe your Scrummaster can answer your question here and show us reference for this behavior. Its definitly not in the Scrum guide: http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-sprint Sprints start with the Sprint planning and not the other way around. If you do it like that you cannot name it Scrum according to the guide. Certified Scrum Masters should know this.

Comment: The biggest con of doing earlier meetings is that its possible to overcommit, due to the fact that your least important stories might not be finished for what ever reason. I can think of one reason to plan it ahead of time, because PO or team-members might be on vacation or others unavailable during the first day of the new sprint.

Comment: Or even your top priority stories are incomplete, and what is actually happening is incomplete stories are being shelved for the next 2 weeks while we do only what we planned in the planning meeting

Comment: I can see that if team members are not able to attend the first day of the sprint it would be worth holding the planning earlier, but this should be the exception, not the norm